# Destructuring map of map with unknown keys

Tags: clojure

I have the following as an example:

```
(def _t2 {:oxnard {:value-type "string" :rec-name "foo"}})
```

where `:oxnard` is ***dynamic and unknown a-priori to function*** and the contained map is made up of well-known key names (e.g. `:value-type` and `:rec-name`).

I'm trying to write a function with destructuring without knowing the outer map keyword, for example:

```
(defn if-foo? [ignoremapfirstkey & 
  {:keys [value-type rec-name]}] 
  (= rec-name "foo"))
```

or similar; however, I can't seem to get around the outer key name not-being known.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your function is passed the dynamic key as an argument, you can use it to extract the inner map, which can then use it to extract the inner map and destructure that:

```
(let [{:keys [foo bar]} (get outer-map :inner-key)]
  ...)

;; k could be a function argument or Var rather than a let local
(let [k :inner-key
      {k {:keys [foo bar]}} outer-map]
  ...)
```

And if the point was that there will always be precisely one entry in the outer map, you can use `first` and `val` to extract the inner map or call `seq` on the map and destructure that:

```
(let [{:keys [foo bar]} (val (first outer-map))]
  ...)

(let [[[_ {:keys [foo bar]}]] (seq outer-map)]
  ...)
```

In the latter case, `(seq outer-map)` will have the form `([k v])` (a seq containing one map entry); the outer vector in the destructuring form destructures the seq, the inner vector destructures the map entry, `_` is a placeholder for the key that you don't care about and `{:keys [foo bar]}` destructures the inner map. You do have to call `seq` on the map yourself, the destructuring machinery won't do it for you.

Comment: The second option is the one that works with the constraint of 'unknown' primary keyword name. Thanks...

Comment: No worries. Also, you absolutely can destructure maps with dynamic keys, just edited the answer to reflect this. Sorry for the confusion, not sure what I was thinking. It's just the names of the locals that can't be dynamic. Also added a `seq`-based alternative to the `val` / `first` solution.

Comment: The 'seq' is even better and is in line with my original thought. Finding the nuances is an uphill crawl. Thanks for the boost!

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
(defmacro somekey
  [complex-map]
  (let [k (first (keys complex-map))]    ; get key from the outer map
    `(let [{inner-map# ~k} ~complex-map] ; use it for destructuring
        inner-map#)))                    ; make this as complex as you want
```

Maybe there's a flaw here and I'm risking downvotes, but it seems to work.  Might not be better than Michal's answer for practical use, even so.  (And of course, other things being equal, it's better to avoid macros unless they're really necessary.)

Comment: This will only work when `complex-map` is passed to the macro as a literal: `{:foo inner-map}`. If it is not, then it will break: `(let [complex-map {:foo {:bar 1}}] (somekey complex-map))`.

Comment: Oh, additionally, if `complex-map` is a map literal with a complex expression as key, `somekey`'s expansion will evaluate this expression twice: `(somekey {(println :foo) {:bar 1}})` prints `:foo` twice.

Comment: Thanks @MichałMarczyk.  It seemed too easy.  I see also that moving the backquote outside the first `let`, and adding/removing `#` and `~` in obvious ways works only on some cases.  No votes for my answer, then.  Maybe it's worth keeping around as a warning.